# Cannot change a value that opens and closes Settings

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

I tried to make a value that let's players know what page are player on and the page can be closed and opened with a value or a button

When I tried to change a value that opens Settings from 1 to 0, it didn't changed. It's just changed back to 1.

There are no error messages, because my code is stable.

I didn't tried any of the fixes because when I looked back at my code, there seems nothing wrong

Here's my code:

```
function openSettings()
    -- Send an event to Server if the Player is opening Settings.
    ReplicatedStorage.OpenSettingsSignal:FireServer()
    
    -- Code
    if player.InteractionsActivity.IsSettingsOpen.Value == 1 then
        TweenService:Create(SettingsPage, quadInOut250ms, nonBackgroundTransparency):Play()
        TweenService:Create(ChoosenTab, quadInOut250ms, nonBackgroundTransparency):Play()
        TweenService:Create(SettingsOption, quadInOut250ms, halfBackgroundTransparency):Play()

        TweenService:Create(ChooseSO, quadInOut250ms, nonBackgroundTransparency):Play()
        TweenService:Create(ChooseSO, quadInOut250ms, nonTextTransparency):Play()
        TweenService:Create(CancelButton, quadInOut250ms, nonBackgroundTransparency):Play()
        TweenService:Create(CancelButton, quadInOut250ms, nonTextTransparency):Play()
        TweenService:Create(DoneButton, quadInOut250ms, nonBackgroundTransparency):Play()
        TweenService:Create(DoneButton, quadInOut250ms, nonTextTransparency):Play()
        TweenService:Create(DisplayButton, quadInOut250ms, nonTextTransparency):Play()

        TweenService:Create(ExclusiveMovileOption, quadInOut250ms, nonTextTransparency):Play()
        TweenService:Create(ScreenOrientation, quadInOut250ms, nonTextTransparency):Play()
        TweenService:Create(DisplayTab, quadInOut250ms, nonTextTransparency):Play()
        TweenService:Create(TitlePage, quadInOut250ms, nonTextTransparency):Play()

        wait(0.25)
        GameGUI.MainMenu.Visible = false

        return nil
    end
    
    TweenService:Create(SettingsPage, quadInOut250ms, nonBackgroundTransparency):Play()
    TweenService:Create(ChoosenTab, quadInOut250ms, nonBackgroundTransparency):Play()
    TweenService:Create(SettingsOption, quadInOut250ms, halfBackgroundTransparency):Play()
    
    TweenService:Create(ChooseSO, quadInOut250ms, nonBackgroundTransparency):Play()
    TweenService:Create(ChooseSO, quadInOut250ms, nonTextTransparency):Play()
    TweenService:Create(CancelButton, quadInOut250ms, nonBackgroundTransparency):Play()
    TweenService:Create(CancelButton, quadInOut250ms, nonTextTransparency):Play()
    TweenService:Create(DoneButton, quadInOut250ms, nonBackgroundTransparency):Play()
    TweenService:Create(DoneButton, quadInOut250ms, nonTextTransparency):Play()
    TweenService:Create(DisplayButton, quadInOut250ms, nonTextTransparency):Play()
    
    TweenService:Create(ExclusiveMovileOption, quadInOut250ms, nonTextTransparency):Play()
    TweenService:Create(ScreenOrientation, quadInOut250ms, nonTextTransparency):Play()
    TweenService:Create(DisplayTab, quadInOut250ms, nonTextTransparency):Play()
    TweenService:Create(TitlePage, quadInOut250ms, nonTextTransparency):Play()
    
    wait(0.25)
    GameGUI.MainMenu.Visible = false
end

function closeSettings()
    -- Send an event to Server if the Player is closing Settings.
    ReplicatedStorage.CloseSettingsSignal:FireServer()

    -- Code
    if player.InteractionsActivity.IsSettingsOpen.Value == 0 or player.InteractionsActivity.IsSettingsOpen.Value > 1 then
        GameGUI.MainMenu.Visible = true
        
        TweenService:Create(SettingsPage, quadInOut250ms, fullBackgroundTransparency):Play()
        TweenService:Create(ChoosenTab, quadInOut250ms, fullBackgroundTransparency):Play()
        TweenService:Create(SettingsOption, quadInOut250ms, fullBackgroundTransparency):Play()

        TweenService:Create(ChooseSO, quadInOut250ms, fullBackgroundTransparency):Play()
        TweenService:Create(ChooseSO, quadInOut250ms, fullTextTransparency):Play()
        TweenService:Create(CancelButton, quadInOut250ms, fullBackgroundTransparency):Play()
        TweenService:Create(CancelButton, quadInOut250ms, fullTextTransparency):Play()
        TweenService:Create(DoneButton, quadInOut250ms, fullBackgroundTransparency):Play()
        TweenService:Create(DoneButton, quadInOut250ms, fullTextTransparency):Play()
        TweenService:Create(DisplayButton, quadInOut250ms, fullTextTransparency):Play()

        TweenService:Create(ExclusiveMovileOption, quadInOut250ms, fullTextTransparency):Play()
        TweenService:Create(ScreenOrientation, quadInOut250ms, fullTextTransparency):Play()
        TweenService:Create(DisplayTab, quadInOut250ms, fullTextTransparency):Play()
        TweenService:Create(TitlePage, quadInOut250ms, fullTextTransparency):Play()
        
        return nil
    end
end

-- Connect to the event When Mouse clicked on Button Element or Something has changed to value to Functions
GameGUI.MainMenu.ProfileMenu.Settings.MouseButton1Click:Connect(openSettings)
GameGUI.MainMenu.SettingsButton.MouseButton1Click:Connect(openSettings)
player.InteractionsActivity.IsSettingsOpen.Changed:Connect(openSettings)
player.InteractionsActivity.IsSettingsOpen.Changed:Connect(closeSettings)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found out how to fix this.

By grouping

is if player.InteractionsActivity.IsSettingsOpen.Value == 1 then
and if player.InteractionsActivity.IsSettingsOpen.Value == 0 then

to 1 function